# selenium, hidden button by overlapped input ( not clickable)

Tags: selenium, cucumber, watir

Is there any way on how to click a hidden button by an overlapped input text field, for example if you go to www.google.com and enter a text to search for, selenium can not find the "Search Google" button because it is hidden by the autocomplete of the text field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass the validation by using `#click!` instead of `#click`. Basically, this triggers the click via JavaScript rather than through standard Selenium commands.

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('www.google.com')
browser.text_field(name: 'q').set('watir')
browser.button(name: 'btnK').click!
```

If you are only using Selenium, you can do:

```
btn = driver.find_element(name: 'btnK')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', btn)
```

As discussed in the comments, you could also close the suggestions box before trying to click the button. You can do this by moving focus to any other element - eg the first link on the page. Depending on what you're testing, this may or may not have value.

```
browser.text_field(name: 'q').set('watir')
browser.link.focus # move focus to any other element so suggestions close
browser.button(name: 'btnK').click
```

Comment: you are the best, I spent the whole day for this, Thanks lot.

Comment: How to do it in selenium if I am not using watir ,?

Comment: @Majid, answer updated with a Selenium-only solution. Though the better solution would be to switch to using Watir.

Comment: @Justin Kom, doesn't it defeat the purpose of the test? If a real user cannot click the button, why would you expect the test to do so?

Comment: @FlorentB. No, it does not! When you manually type something in the text filed, it would populate with possible lists and this list is hiding the search button, but when you manually work with this text_field, you can move away the cursor thereby the list would disappear and then you can able to click the search button.

Comment: @RAJ, if the button were to be hidden (`stye.display = 'none'` or overlaid), or if the code supposed to hide the list were to break, it would be manually impossible to click this button. On the other hand `click!` would be since it doesn't assert whether the button is interactable. So using `click!` is pointless in testing since it doesn't guaranty that a real user can interact with it. Note that you could probably handle/hide this list by pressing the escape/tab key or by clicking another element.

Comment: Florent B, how can you accomplish what you said "Note that you could probably handle/hide this list by pressing the escape/tab key or by clicking another element" in watir or selenium ? can you give us an example ? Thanks,

Comment: @Majid, an example of closing the suggestions list has been added to the answer. Depending what you're testing, there may or may not be value in this extra step.